# redux-form wizard with ant.design or antd Steps

Tags: wizard, redux-form, antd, react-redux-form

I want to use redux-form with antd normal components can be handled via renderField component but I want to use antd Steps https://ant.design/components/steps/ with redux-form. How to implement this? Can someone guide me?

Comment: At Stack Overflow you will get better help if you make some initial effort at solving the problem yourself, and ask questions (showing your code so far) when you run into trouble.

Comment: thats true working that out basically i am new to redux-form we were already using antd, so still need to work out on redux-form it worked pretty well with other controls b.c we can pass renderControl in components but wizard is the point I got stuck

Comment: Instead of asking for general guidance you should describe how far you have gotten (or understood), and exactly what it is you got stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is where i started from:

- [Redux-form wizard form](https://codesandbox.io/s/0qzz3843?from-embed)
- [Antd steps](https://codesandbox.io/s/x24nqzvzjo)

and here is my redux-form with antd steps combined.
The `<Form />` is inside the modal. Steps are stored in redux store. In my case steps are controlled by saga (if response success > increment to step 3, if requires additional verification > increment to step 2 etc...) but you can  increment/set steps by clicking next/submit or decrement/reset steps by clicking on previous/close modal.

```
const Form = ({ hide, isLoading, step, name, setStep }) => (
  <FormCard>
    {step === 1 && <StepOneText name={name} />}
    {step === 2 && <StepTwoText name={name} />}
    {step === 3 && <StepThreeText name={name} hide={hide} />}
    <Steps
      initial={1}
      size="small"
      current={step}
      style={{ padding: '20px 0' }}
    >
      <Step
        status={stepStatus(step)}
        title="Auth"
        icon={<Icon type={step === 1 && isLoading ? 'loading' : 'user'} />}
      />
      <Step
        title="Verify"
        icon={<Icon type={step === 2 && isLoading ? 'loading' : 'solution'} />}
      />
      <Step
        status={step === 3 ? 'finish' : 'wait'}
        title="Done"
        icon={<Icon type="smile-o" />}
      />
    </Steps>
    {step === 1 && <RegisterForm />}
    {step === 2 && <ChallengeForm />}
    {step === 3 && <CallForAction hide={hide} setStep={setStep} />}
  </FormCard>
);
```